# Run time error 1004 when trying to find row

Tags: vba, excel

was wondering if anyone could help me solve the following problem.
 I'm given a runtime error 1004, over at `With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rowtosave, EGCheck)` Have spent quite some time trying out but still unable to define the error myself. Should anyone nice, care to help me out? Will appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim LastRow1 As Long, RowCheck As Long, Rowtosave As Long, LastCol1 As Long
Dim EGCheck As Long, ColEG As Range, firstEG As Long


LastRow1 = 50
LastCol1 = 50

   For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1
'Look for "Name"
     With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCheck, 1)
         If .Value = "Name" Then
     'Set row to Rowtosave for later use
           Rowtosave = RowCheck

         End If
    End With

 Next RowCheck

     For EGCheck = 1 To LastCol1
      'Look for EG on the name row with varying column
      'Since already obtain the row for name as Rowtosave, so set Row to Rowtosave
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rowtosave, EGCheck)
          If .Value = "EG" Then

           firstEG = EGCheck

         End If
       End With

Next EGCheck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something wrong with your situation that isn't shown here. When I enter the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, RowCheck As Long, Rowtosave As Long
    Dim LastCol1 As Long, EGCheck As Long

    Range("a1:a1").Value = -1

    LastRow1 = 50
    LastCol1 = 50

    For RowCheck = 1 To LastRow1
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowCheck, 1)
            If .Value = "Name" Then
                Rowtosave = RowCheck
            End If
        End With
    Next RowCheck

    For EGCheck = 1 To LastCol1
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rowtosave, EGCheck)
            If .Value = "EG" Then
                Range("a1:a1").Value = Rowtosave * 10 + EGCheck
            End If
        End With
    Next EGCheck
End Sub
```

and put `Name` and `EG` into cells `A6` and `D6` respectively, I end up with a `64` in cell `A1`, as expected. In other words, it's working fine.

However, if I *remove* `Name` from cell `A6`, I get the error 1004, same as you. That's because, in that case, `Rowtocheck` is never being set, hence it will have it's default value of zero.

And, when you attempt to use 0 as the rown in the `Cells()` call, it errors because the row must be one or more.

Comment: hi, thanks! I'm not sure why on mine page, it isnt working.. anyway, i have tried to place the EGCheck loop into my RowCheck loop, it is working fine too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your sample data is, it's hard to say.  But i suspect that the condition that sets "Rowtosave" is never being met, so Rowtosave = 0.  There is no row/column 0, so when the suspect line in your code runs (this line):

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rowtosave, EGCheck)
```

, it errors.

Comment: thanks for your comment! will have a look at it again.. but when i compile them together as a single loop, no problem was faced